# Why is this puzzle solved

Tags: puzzles, chess.com

I did the following puzzle on chess.com:

[image: initial configuration]

And it shows solved with the following configuration:

[image: final solution]

I do not see why this is a solution. Black can take the Rook, and I don't see how to punish it.

Comment: Please clarify the line which shows how you get to the position on the second picture. You can use special board of this website to interactively show the line, [help page](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post).

Comment: I wonder how you got the second position. 1. Rg3 g6 2. Rxg6 Kf7 3. Rxf6+. Was it the continuation? Cause 1. Rg3 g6 2. Rxg6 Bxg6 3. Qxg6+black is in trouble though material is equal if black's king wasn't in check then it will be possible to equalize the position by .... Qg4+. The answer to your question given below so I am not writing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After **2. Rxf6+** Black is fighting to survive and **2...Kxf6** is Black's only way to delay the final result (assuming best play).  White must respond with **3. Rxg6!** which is the only move to maintain the advantage.

Black gets a very vulnerable King while White gets an active Queen and Rook with good coordination and a safer King.

After **3...Ke5 4. Qg3+** Black is forced to choose

- between losing the Queen with 4...Qf4 5. Re6+, or
- playing 4...f4 which is the human move (Engine wants to lose the Queen),

yet this f4-pawn push still loses to 5. Qg5+ as illustrated.

One commenter points out that the 6. Qxh5 is unclear.  I agree that 6. Qe7+ forking the King and Rook is the human move and the most practical move. I would play that as well.

For those interested, the less practical line 6. Qxh5 wins as well and leads to a situation where Black must either give up the Queen or submit to a forced mate.

```
[Title "Black is in Trouble"]
[FEN "5r2/6k1/1p2Rbp1/p2p1p1p/2q5/2P1R3/PP3PQ1/6K1 w - - 0 1"]

1. Rg3 Kf7 2. Rxf6+ Kxf6 3. Rxg6+! Ke5 4. Qg3+ f4 (4. Qh2+ {Also fine for White}) 5. Qg5+ Ke4 (5... Rf5? 6. Qe7#) 6. Qe7+ Kd3 7. Qxf8
(4...Qf4 5. Re6+ Kxe6 6. Qxf4)
(6. Qxh5 Kd3 7. Qd1+ Ke4 8. f3+ Kf5 9. Qb1+ {Black must give up the Queen or there's a forced mate in 10})
```

Comment: The variation ending 6 Qxh5 doesn't look conclusive: material is even and after Kd3 the bK might successfully hide and even star in a Q-side counterattack ending with a1Q.  Instead 6 Qe7+ wins a Rook since 6 . . . Kf5 gives White a choice of two mates in one.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I've updated my answer to finish the line.  I agree with you that 6. Qe7+ is the more practical and human move.  I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: Please correct a few typos. BTW, baaad puzzle, it is very hard to calculate a king chase with heavy artillery just in your head. That notwithstanding, as soon as I realize my rook stays on the g file, I play the line even in blitz without hesitation.

Comment: You missed a typo, I think--you have the alternate move 5... Rf5? which is not legal by standard chess rules--it's black capturing a black pawn.

Comment: The typo is in "4. Qg3+ Qf4" -- should be Qg3+ f4 (as it stands, the reply "5. Qg5+" is neither check nor good; White refutes Qf4 with 5 Re6+). Also, the initial moves in "Black is in Trouble" don't quite produce the diagram that **Lot** gave; my guess was 1 Rg3 g5 2 Rxg5+ Kf7 3 Rxf6+.

Comment: I fixed one typo, but I'm confident others exist. I just don't know how to fix them.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I was wondering what was happening. Thanks for pointing out.. SecretAgentMan correct the mistakes. 5. Qh4??

Comment: Some PGN mistakes corrected.  Made some typos.  Hope to fix others later today when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

It's won for White because Q+R coordinate to attack the exposed bK which Black can't defend for long.

I assume you started 1 Rg3 g5 2 Rxg5+ Kf7 3 Rxf6+.  Then Kxf6 4 Rg6+ and now:

4 ... Ke7 5 Qg7+ Rf7 (Kd8 6 Qg5+ Kc8 7 Qe7 and mates soon) 6 Qg5+ Ke8 (Ke6 7 Qg6+ Rf6 8 Qe8+ as in the next variation) 7 Rg8+ Kd7 (Rf8 8 Qg6+) 8 Qd8+ Kc6 9 Qe8+ Rd7 10 Rg7 1-0

4 ... Kf7 5 Rg7+ Ke6(f6) (or Ke8 6 Qg6+ Kd8 7 Qd6+ and mate) 6 Qg6+ Ke5 (Rf6 7 Qe8+ Kd6 8 Qe7+ Kc6 9 Qxf6+) 7 Re7+ Kf4 8 Qg3#

4 ... Ke5 5 Qg3+ f4 (Qf4 6 Re6+ Kxe6 7 Qxf4) 6 Qg5+ Ke4 (Rf5 7 Qe7#) 7 Qe7+ wins the Rook.  Black can try to counterattack with Kf3 8 Qxf8 Qe2 but 9 Rg3+ ends it (the pin prevents fxg3, and after Ke4 10 Qe8+ skewers the Queen).